# sort array of date-months in ascending order of type string

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var months = ["April 2021","March 2021", "May 2021", "April 2020"];
```

how to get ascending order of these months of type string.

```
let monthArray = ["January", "Febraury", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

let preparedArray = [];

months.forEach(month => {
    let mntSplit = month.split(' ');
    preparedArray.push({year: mntSplit[1], month: mntSplit[0] });
});
```

how to proceed to asc sort  please help

Comment: Can you post example of the output array which you want

Comment: resultExpected  = ["April 2020","March 2021","April 2021","May 2021"] like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor

```js
var months = ["April 2021", "March 2021", "May 2021", "April 2020"]

var sorted = months.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))

console.log(sorted)
```

**Update:** (not working in firefox)

```js
var months = ["April 2021", "March 2021", "May 2021", "April 2020"]

var sorted = months.sort((a, b) => new Date('01 ' + a) - new Date('01 ' + b))

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: not working in firefox browser

Comment: @ShaikHabeeb Sorry I never knew that. It's due to the date missing from the list.

Comment: hi, Can you explain to me what changed with the parameters `('01 ' + a)` and `('01 ' + a)` inside the new Data instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code you can use this:

```js
var months = ["April 2021","March 2021", "May 2021", "April 2020"];
let monthArray = ["January", "Febraury", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

months = months.sort((a,b)=>{
  const [monthA, yearA] = a.split(' '),
        [monthB, yearB] = b.split(' ');
  if (yearA === yearB)
    return monthArray.indexOf(monthA) - monthArray.indexOf(monthB);
  return +yearA - +yearB
})

console.log(months)
```

Otherwise sort by using `new Date()`:

```
months.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
```

Comment: months.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
 it is not working in firefox